# Python - search for string in array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array of strings:

```
["aaa 1", "aaa 2", "bbb 2", "ccc 3", "ddd 4"]
```

I need to search for some string in this vector, but only the first part. For example, I need the position of the strings starting with `"aaa"` (in this example, that would be 0 and 1).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> lst = ["aaa 1", "aaa 2", "bbb 2", "ccc 3", "ddd 4"]
>>> [x for x,y in enumerate(lst) if y.split()[0] == "aaa"]
[0, 1]
>>>
```

`y.split()[0]` will split the string on spaces and return the first element.  Thus:

```
if y.split()[0] == "aaa"
```

only checks the first part of each string.  If however the strings are always like those given in your example, a simple [`in` membership test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) will suffice:

```
[x for x,y in enumerate(lst) if "aaa" in y]
```

Answer (score 2):

Us [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) :

```
>>> l =  ["aaa 1", "aaa 2", "bbb 2", "ccc 3", "ddd 4"]
>>> print [ind for ind, ele in enumerate(l) if ele.startswith("aaa")]
[0, 1]
```

`ind` is the index of each element in your list, `ele` is each element, so if the string starts with "aaa" we add the index to the list

If there is no chance you will have `"aaa"` in the second half of the string or a substring of the first half just using [in](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) will be the most efficient

```
[ind for ind, ele in enumerate(l) if "aaa" in ele]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list. In order to go through each item you can:

```
for eachlistitem in listname:
    if eachlistem[:3] == "ABC": #this only checks first three char of current list item
        ##do something here like increment a counter
        ##add counter # to new list to have a list of locations
```